# add new Mongo module in play framework 2.4

Tags: java, playframework-2.4

I am developing an application using Play Framework 2.4. I was trying to add Mongo module by following [this](https://www.playframework.com/modules/mongo-1.3/home) URL.
It says to put `module.mongo=${play.path}/modules/mongo` in application.conf & as `play` command is replaced by `activator` command in version 2.4, so i put path of my `activator` at the place of `${play.path1}`, but it hasn’t loaded the Mongo module.
I also tried [this](https://www.playframework.com/modules/mongo) URL, as at the bottom of page `play install mongo-{version}` command is written, i tried it by using `activator install mongo-1.3` but as `activator` don't have `install` option.
I also tried by adding `require:- play -> mongo {version}` in `conf/dependencies.yml` but it still dosen't work.
Now, please let me know, how can i install Mongo Module in my Play project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB Module is not supported for Play 2.x as the documentation clearly states: https://www.playframework.com/modules/mongo

You can however integrate MongoDB easily with the official [Mongo Java Driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/)

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver" % "3.0.4"
)
```

It includes an async dirver since v3.0.